# Applied for a UK 6-month tourist visa

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for a UK tourist standard visa before 14 working days and I'm 26 years old. I have submitted almost 1 year of bank statements, with a closing balance of 1.8 million IDR. I have showed the business account of my tours and travels and income tax proof, my education certificate, our properties details, which is in my father's name. I was rejected twice 5 years ago. Will my visa be approved?

Comment: Nobody can definitely answer this except the officer assigned to assessing your application.

Comment: Google tells me that  1.8 million Indonesian Rupees are equivalent to 111 € or 90 GBP. Are those numbers correct?

Answer (score 1):

No-one can predict what the decision will be. If you’ve materially improved your personal circumstances (finances, ties to home, travel history etc) over the last 5 years, such that you’ve addressed the refusal reason(s), you have as good a chance as any other applicant in your situation. Property details in your father’s name won’t influence the outcome at all.